# Change some (not all) header heights in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

JSBin link: https://jsbin.com/xofaco/edit?html,css,output

I have an html table where three of the columns have a nested header but three do not. I am trying to find a way to have the header be one equal height, where the columns labeled "four, five, six" match the height of the "Admissions" nested header.

I've tried a solution where I had empty `<th></th>` and used borders to make it appear as though they stretched the full height but that is not my preferred solution.

I've attached my jsbin link above, let me know if any additional information is needed.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th, td, tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.one {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="table-wrapper table-wrapper--no-scroll table-wrapper--row-header-border table-wrapper--no-cell-wrapping">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
          <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup" class="table-wrapper--no-top-border">Admissions Top Heading</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th scope-"col" class="table-wrapper--no-top-border">one</th>
          <th scope-"col" class="table-wrapper--no-top-border">two</th>
          <th scope-"col" class="table-wrapper--no-top-border">three</th>
          <th scope-"col" class="one">four</th>
          <th scope-"col" class="one">five</th>
          <th scope-"col" class="one">six</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">March 2016</th>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">April 2016</th>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">May 2016</th>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML structure by moving columns `four` `five` and `six` to first `tr` and also after you move change `th` to `td` with `rowspan="2"`

So your first `tr` must look like below. Here is you [updated bin](https://jsbin.com/fokohociku/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup" class="table-wrapper--no-top-border">Admissions Top Heading</th>
  <td rowspan="2" scope- "col" class="one">four</td>
  <td rowspan="2" scope- "col" class="one">five</td>
  <td rowspan="2" scope- "col" class="one">six</td>
</tr>
```

Below is a working snippet

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.one {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
      <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup" class="table-wrapper--no-top-border">Admissions Top Heading</th>
      <td rowspan="2" scope- "col" class="one">four</td>
      <td rowspan="2" scope- "col" class="one">five</td>
      <td rowspan="2" scope- "col" class="one">six</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope- "col" class="table-wrapper--no-top-border">one</th>
      <th scope- "col" class="table-wrapper--no-top-border">two</th>
      <th scope- "col" class="table-wrapper--no-top-border">three</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">March 2016</th>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">April 2016</th>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">May 2016</th>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
      <td>###</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```